# Animation not playing through script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the game I'm making to play an animation when you butter toast but I tried this but it didn't work. This animation is susposed to make the screen fade to yellow. I'm new to coding so don't try to verabally abuse my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Toast : MonoBehaviour
{
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit raycastHit;
    public Camera cam;
    public GameObject ButterIt;
    private float myTimer = 0f;
    private bool isCounting = false;
    private Animation anim;
    public GameObject yellow;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
        yellow.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward * 100);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit))
        {
            if (raycastHit.transform.tag == "Death")
            {
                ButterIt.SetActive(true);
                if (Input.GetKeyDown("f"))
                {
                    Debug.Log("Stop Touching My Junk You Pervert! - Tickle Me Bender");
                    isCounting = true;
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                ButterIt.SetActive(false);
            }
        }

        if (isCounting)
        {
            myTimer += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (myTimer > 2.5f)
        {
            yellow.SetActive(true);
            Debug.Log("WEE WOO WEE WOO - Patrick");
            isCounting = false;
            anim.Play("YellowFade");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code I know it's bad.